# how can I sum values from related collection in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am fairly new to MongoDB, having background in SQL databases. I have 2 collections : an invoice collections and payments collection that holds payment documents for each invoice. I need to retrieve all the invoices and also have a field named totalPayedAmount that sums the amount of the total payments for that invoice. I was thinking of doing this by adding a field in the invoice collection named totalPayedAmount and updating it each time I add a new payment for that invoice. I think in MongoDB this can be made easier with aggregation functions or with mapReduce but I am not really sure how

This is the schema:

```
invoice collection:
{
    _id
    invoiceNumber
    ...
}

payment collection:
{
    _id
    invoiceId
    amount
}
```

Comment: Both operations are very well documented on the MongoDb site. What problems are you encountering with the code you've written?

Comment: I don't know what do use in order to calculate the total amount for each invoice :)...I am fairly new to mongo

Comment: by running the "aggregate" query on payment collection you could get the result of records {_id: invoiceId, totalAmount: <number>}. It would be quite an easy aggregate pipeline. Examples given on http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/ are quite easy to understand.